# How to run and interpret Fisher's Linear Discriminant Analysis from scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to run a Fisher's LDA ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis), [2](http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/lineardiscriminantanalysis.php)) to reduce the number of features of matrix.

Basically, correct if I am wrong, given n samples classified in several classes, Fisher's LDA tries to find an axis that projecting thereon should maximize the value J(w), which is the ratio of total sample variance to the sum of variances within separate classes.

I think this can be used to find the most useful features for each class.

I have a matrix X of m features and n samples (m rows, n columns).

I have a sample classification y, i.e. an array of n labels, each one for each sample.

Basing on y I want to reduce the number of features to, for example, 3 most representative features.

Using `scikit-learn` I tried in this way (following [this documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.lda.LDA.html)):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.lda import LDA
>>> X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
>>> y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
>>> clf = LDA(n_components=3)
>>> clf.fit_transform(X, y)
array([[ 4.],
   [ 4.],
   [ 8.],
   [-4.],
   [-4.],
   [-8.]])
```

At this point I am a bit confused, how to obtain the most representative features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The features you are looking for are in `clf.coef_` after you have fitted the classifier.

Note that `n_components=3` doesn't make sense here, since `X.shape[1] == 2`, i.e. your feature space only has two dimensions.

You do not need to invoke `fit_transform` in order to obtain `coef_`, calling `clf.fit(X, y)` will suffice.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was in the hurry of asking and I did not notice that 3 did not make sense (even because I work with a cardinality of ~10000 features). I try `coef_` and let you know. Thanks

Comment: A related question: `clf.coef_` gives me an array of 2 elements even if I put 4/5 features for each sample and I do not specify `n_components`. Is there a way to know which features have been selected? Or I misunderstood the way LDA works?

Comment: Maybe using `clf.xbar_` and taking the n features with higher absolute value?

Comment: `xbar_` is the overall mean of features. Yes, `clf.coef_` never has more lines than classes and has `n_classes - 1` columns, so 1 in your case. It represents the features used by the decision function, but they live in a rescaled space. Take a look at `LDA._decision_function??` in an IPython to see how the data are recentered and rescaled before `coef_` is used. In order to interpret `coef_` in the original feature space, you could e.g. rescale it by applying the pseudoinverse of `LDA.scalings_`

Comment: To rescale you mean something like this: `np.dot(clf.coef_, np.linalg.pinv(clf.scalings_))` ? I obtain a matrix of (m x n) entries where m is the number of features and n the number of classes..