# Probabilistic linear discrimnant Analysis

Tags: python, lda

Does python have any library that I can use for either fisher's linear discriminant Analysis or probabilistic linear discriminant Analysis? In a dead end

Comment: Note that asking for library recommendations is offtopic.

Comment: I know  but didnt know where to ask that, I've searched around and wanted to know if the community could point me in the right direction

Comment: Please don't knowingly post offtopic questions. If it's offtopic, it's offtopic. Context doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [sklearn.discriminant_analysis](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html)?  There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277958/how-to-run-and-interpret-fishers-linear-discriminant-analysis-from-scikit-learn) potentially related question.